# How to use Json on android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Below is my json file structure. 
I want to draw graph(x-axis : time, y-axis : "close" value)

```
{
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "stock_exchange_short": "NASDAQ",
    "timezone_name": "America/New_York",
    "intraday": {
        2018-10-19 15:59:00: {
            "open": "219.49",
            "close": "219.23",
            "high": "219.61",
            "low": "219.19",
            "volume": "302415",
        },
        2018-10-19 15:58:00: {
            "open": "219.62",
            "close": "219.48",
            "high": "219.70",
            "low": "219.48",
            "volume": "173762",
        },
        2018-10-19 15:57:00: {
            "open": "219.54",
            "close": "219.64",
            "high": "219.66",
            "low": "219.46",
            "volume": "130992",
        },
        2018-10-19 15:56:00: {
            "open": "219.71",
            "close": "219.57",
            "high": "219.77",
            "low": "219.57",
            "volume": "113398",
        },
        ...
    }
 }
```

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
      JsonArray arr = response.getJsonArray("intraday")??
```

What I want to get is hashmap that contains "data" as key and "close value" as value for each time. Can anyone tell me how to get it

Comment: what do you mean by 'data' as key? means do you want "open", "close, "low","volume" as key?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same key('data') for all close values.

`Hash map` key is unique. if you add duplicate `key`, then it will be overwritten.

I have given an example of `hashmap` with unique key (time) in my below answer.

You can parse your JSON like the following.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     JSONObject intradayObj = response.getJSONObject("intraday");

     HashMap<String, String> yourMap = new HashMap();   

     Iterator<?> keys = intradayObj.keys();
     while(keys.hasNext()) {
         String key = (String)keys.next();
         if (intradayObj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {

             JSONObject dateTimeJsonObj = intradayObj.optJSONObject(key);
             if (dateTimeJsonObj == null) {
                continue;
             }
             // get close value 
             String closeValue = dateTimeJsonObj.getString("close")
             Log.d("TAG", "Your Close value "+closeValue);

             // you can others value like close
             String openValue = dateTimeJsonObj.getString("open") 
             // ....


             // here you can store close value
             yourMap.put(getTime(key), closeValue)
         }
     }

      // finally your hashmap will look like (x-axis : time, y-axis : "close" value)
      // ("15:59:00", "219.23")
      // ("15:58:00", "219.48")
      // ("15:57:00", "219.64")
      // ("15:56:00", "219.57")

}
```

To get time from `String` date-time

```
public String getTime(String dateTime){
   try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = df.parse(dateTime);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String shortTimeStr = sdf.format(date);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); 
   }
   return shortTimeStr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `JSONArrayListener` to `JSONObjectListener` on `OnResponse()`. Also, Add your datetimestamp inside the object like this.

From this:

```
 {
"symbol": "AAPL",
"stock_exchange_short": "NASDAQ",
"timezone_name": "America/New_York",
"intraday": {
    2018-10-19 15:59:00: {
        "open": "219.49",
        "close": "219.23",
        "high": "219.61",
        "low": "219.19",
        "volume": "302415",
    },
    2018-10-19 15:58:00: {
        "open": "219.62",
        "close": "219.48",
        "high": "219.70",
        "low": "219.48",
        "volume": "173762",
    },
    2018-10-19 15:57:00: {
        "open": "219.54",
        "close": "219.64",
        "high": "219.66",
        "low": "219.46",
        "volume": "130992",
    },
    2018-10-19 15:56:00: {
        "open": "219.71",
        "close": "219.57",
        "high": "219.77",
        "low": "219.57",
        "volume": "113398",
    },
    ...
}
```

}

to

```
{
"symbol": "AAPL",
"stock_exchange_short": "NASDAQ",
"timezone_name": "America/New_York",
"intraday": {
    "data": [
        {
            "open": "219.49",
            "close": "219.23",
            "high": "219.61",
            "low": "219.19",
            "volume": "302415",
            "datetimestamp": "2018-10-19 15:59:00"
        },
        {
            "open": "219.62",
            "close": "219.48",
            "high": "219.70",
            "low": "219.48",
            "volume": "173762",
            "datetimestamp": "2018-10-19 15:59:00"
        },
        {
            "open": "219.54",
            "close": "219.64",
            "high": "219.66",
            "low": "219.46",
            "volume": "130992",
            "datetimestamp": "2018-10-19 15:59:00"
        },
        {
            "open": "219.71",
            "close": "219.57",
            "high": "219.77",
            "low": "219.57",
            "volume": "113398",
            "datetimestamp": "2018-10-19 15:59:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Then get the data by doing this (btw, I'm using `AndroidNetworking`):

```
 AndroidNetworking.get("your URL")
            .addHeaders("your Header")
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try{

                        //getting intraday as a JSONObject
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("intraday");

                         HashMap<String, String> yourMap = new HashMap();   


                        //getting the data as a JSONArray as given on my example
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                        for (int x = 0;x< jsonArray.length();x++){

                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x);

                            //getting the data inside the json object
                            double open = jsonObject1.getDouble("open");
                            double close = jsonObject1.getDouble("close");
                            double high = jsonObject1.getDouble("high");
                            double low = jsonObject1.getDouble("low");
                            int volume = jsonObject1.getInt("volume"); //or getDouble it depends on your data
                            String dateTimeStamp = jsonObject1.getString("datetimestamp");

                            try {
                            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            Date date = df.parse(dateTimeStamp);
                           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                           String convertedDateTimeStamp = sdf.format(date);
                           } catch (ParseException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace(); 
                          }

                            yourMap.put(convertedDateTimeStamp, String.valueOf(close))
                        }
                    }catch (Throwable throwable){
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: why he needs to change `intraday to a JSONArray`?  in your new `JSON format`  `intraday` is a `JSONObject`('data' is a `JSONArray`). is not it?

Comment: @JakirHossain ow sorry, I miss typed it. I will change it real quick. thank you for reminding me